# unicode endian puzzled me

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, endianness, ucs2

i edit three  files which have same content "你"(is `you` in english) in it in three different forms--gbk\utf-8\ucs-2  with gedit  named "ok1,ok2,ok3".

```
>>> f1 = open('ok1', 'rb').read()
>>> f2 = open('ok2', 'rb').read()
>>> f3 = open('ok3', 'rb').read()
>>> f1
'\xc4\xe3\n'
>>> f2
'\xe4\xbd\xa0\n'
>>> f3
'`O\n\x00'
>>> hex(ord("`"))
'0x60'
>>> hex(ord("O")) 
'0x4f'
```

in fact f3 is '\x60\x4f',
but the following output confused me

```
>>> '\xe4\xbd\xa0'.decode("utf-8")
u'\u4f60'
>>> '\xc4\xe3'.decode("gbk")
u'\u4f60'
>>>
```

why only there is endian problem in ucs-2(or say unicode) ,not in utf-8,not in gbk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*UTF-8* and *GBK* store data in a sequence of bytes. It is strongly defined which byte value comes after which in these encodings. This byte order does not change with the architecture used in coding, transmission or decoding.

On the other hand, *UCS-2* or the new *UTF-16* store data in sequences of 2-bytes. The order of individual bytes within these 2-byte tokens is the *endianness* and it depends on the underlying machine architecture. Systems must have an agreement on how to identify the endianness of tokens before communicating with data encoded in *UCS-2*.

In your case, Unicode point U+4F60 is coded in *UCS-2* as a single 2-byte token `0x4F60`. Since your machine puts the least significant byte before the most significant one in memory alignment, the sequence `('0x60', '0x4F')` has been put into the file. Thus, file read will yield the bytes in this order.

Python can still decode this data correctly since it will read the bytes in correct order before forming the 2-byte token:

```
>>> '`O\n\x00'.decode('utf-16')
u'\u4f60\n'
```

Comment: Since your machine puts the least significant byte before the most significant one in memory alignment, the sequence ('0x60', '0x4F') has been put into the file. Thus, file read will yield the bytes in this order.why  in my machine, f1 is not '\xe3\xc4\n'?? f2 is not  f2   '\xbd\xe4\xa0\n'

Comment: @Dd Pp: Because when writing a utf-8 file, gedit puts bytes *one-by-one*. However, when writing a ucs-2 coded file, gedit puts the bytes *two-by-two*. The order within bytes depends on the endianness only in the latter case.

Answer (score 5):

Endian-ness only applies to multi-byte words, but UTF-8 uses units of 8 bits to encode information (that's what the 8 in the name stands for). There never is the question of confusion of ordering there.

Sometimes it may need more than one of those units to encode information, but they are considered distinct. The letter `A` is one byte, `0x41`, for example. When it has to encode a character with more bytes, it uses a leading indicator byte, followed by extra continuation bytes to capture all the information needed for that character. Logically, these are distinct units.

GBK uses a similar scheme; characters use units of 1 byte, and just like UTF-8, a second byte can be used for some of the characters.

UCS-2 (and it's successor, UTF-16) on the other hand, is a 2-byte format. It encodes information in units of 16 bits, and those 16 bits always go together. The 2 bytes in that unit belong together logically, and modern architectures treat these as one unit, and thus have made a decision in what order they are stored. That's where endianess comes in, the order of the 2 bytes in a unit is architecture dependant. In *your* architecture, the bytes are ordered using little-endianess, meaning that the 'smaller' byte goes first. This is why the `0x4F` byte comes before the `0x60` byte in your file.

Note that python can read either big or little endian UTF-16 just fine; you can pick the endianess explicitly if there is no indicator character at the start (the Byte Order Mark, or BOM):

```
>>> '`O\n\x00'.decode('utf-16')
u'\u4f60\n'
>>> '`O\n\x00'.decode('utf-16-le')
u'\u4f60\n'
>>> 'O`\x00\n'.decode('utf-16-be')
u'\u4f60\n'
```

In the latter example the bytes have been reversed, and decoded as big-endian.